# How to use Debounce Time without subscribing to it

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

i have a Service witch extends TitleService witch have this method

```
setTitle(newTitle: string) {
    super.setTitle(newTitle+'TEST');
}
```

I wanted to set the Title after 2 seconds after the method is called, using debounceTime but i dont want to subscribe to it.

The reason why i need DebounceTime is beacuse if the user trigger the events countles times, then the title would be the last one.

Is there any solution?

Comment: what do you mean by: "i dont want to subscribe to it" ? And why?

Comment: I used this method in like 20 components, i dont want the subscriber to effect each other

Comment: I think you should use setTimeout() instead of debounceTime while you're not dealing with reactive way

Comment: I am dealing with reactive way, i need just the latest Title

Comment: @Roffex if my answer has helped you, could you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Subject in your CustomTitleService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'
import { debounceTime, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomTitleService {
  titleSubject = new Subject<string>()

  constructor(
    private titleService: Title
  ) {
    this.titleSubject
      .pipe(
        startWith(this.titleService.getTitle()),
        debounceTime(2000) // adjust, here it's 2 sec
      )
      .subscribe(title =>
        this.titleService.setTitle(title)
      )
  }

  setTitle(newTitle: string) {
    this.titleSubject.next(`${newTitle} TEST`)
  }
}
```

Note that in the official Angular documentation, it is noted that the class Title is final and hence should not be extended. This is why I've maded the CustomTitleService be a wrapper of the Title service instead: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title